# Error PPA ehoover has no release file

Tags: apt, updates

Here is the error message I get while running `sudo apt update`:

```
Hit:1 http://vn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://vn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease              
Hit:3 http://vn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease            
Hit:4 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ehoover/compholio/ubuntu focal InRelease        
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease               
Err:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ehoover/compholio/ubuntu focal Release          
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Hit:8 https://brinkervii.gitlab.io/grapejuice/repositories/debian universal InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ehoover/compholio/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Please follow the link http://ppa.launchpad.net/ehoover/compholio/ubuntu to know that the latest available Ubuntu version from this PPA is Ubuntu 16.04 xenial → http://ppa.launchpad.net/ehoover/compholio/ubuntu/dists/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your repository list [has a 404 PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eehoover/+archive/ubuntu/compholio) which is no longer maintained. It was last updated  more than 5 years ago! I suggest removing it.

1. Remove the PPA

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ehoover/compholio
   ```
2. Update the repository list:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```

That's it! 
Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you stranger, your kindness will live in my heart forever

Comment: @TheCool_K1DS Awesome! Glad it's working as expected. Please accept this answer by clicking the checkmark button near the vote count. Enjoy!